# WSO2 API Manager: setting https endpoint

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I create an API where I configure the endpoint: https://ssl.croinform.ru:450/api.test
And there is a problem with https, I am not getting a response to the request. It seems the WSO2 API Manager API gateway is not proxying requests to the endpoint.
When I make requests directly, I pre-configure the infrastructure: install the openssl counterpart, install the cacer.p7b and ssl.croinform.cer certificates. After that, I successfully receive responses from the ssl.croinform.ru:450/api.test service.

Can you tell me what I need to do to make this work in WSO2 API Manager?

Comment: I also do not understand where the keytool utility is located and how to use it. I am running WSO2 API Manager on Windows from a .bat file. Do I understand correctly that we are talking about the windows command line utility (keytool)?

Comment: In git bash, I tried importing the certificates this way:
1) keytool -importcert -file ssl.croinform.cer -alias croinformbackend -keystore "C: / Program Files / wso2am-3.2.0 / repository / resources / security / client-truststore.jks"
2) keytool -importcert -file cacer.p7b -alias cacerbackend -keystore "C: / Program Files / wso2am-3.2.0 / repository / resources / security / client-truststore.jks"
3) keytool -importcert -file cacer.p7b -alias cacer -keystore backend-truststore.jks keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate.

Comment: Only one attempt was successful:
keytool -importcert -file ssl.croinform.cer -alias croinform -keystore backend-truststore.jks 
I guess I'm doing something wrong))

Comment: You can add a cert for the Endpoint - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/design-api/endpoints/certificates/#adding-a-certificate-for-an-endpoint